# I am unable to import js file from dynamic path

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to import a js file with static path which is working fine, but when I change path to dynamic it give me the error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at common.js:1:1)
main.80ab3b6a.js:942 undefined) if I put the path static like ~/ALLPATH/translation/en/tarnslate.js then it is working, but if I change it to dynamic then give me the error

```
const ln = $scope.locale;

if (ln) {
  $scope.commonLang = (await import(`~/ALLPATH/translation/translation/${ln}/tarnslate.js`)).languages;

  console.log($scope.commonLang);
}
```

Comment: *"then give me the error"* which error?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at translate.js:1:1)
main.80ab3b6a.js:942 undefined

Comment: Looks like the value of `ln` is so that the URL points to a non-existing file. Check your developer tools and network requests.

Comment: the path is exactly same in both cases

Comment: Then maybe your build process cannot identify the file because of the dynamic path and doesn't put it in the target directory. The error seems to indicate that the server returns a 404 response for this path, which includes HTML, hence the error about an unexpected `<` character. That's all I can say about this issue with the information you have provided.

Comment: yes thats my question why dynamic path is not loading, is it loading later than function called